# Expandablelistview adapter from phpmyadmin

Tags: android, mysql, expandablelistview

I'd like to make expandable listview in android of product's list which grouped by the category. I'm using phpmyadmin as my database. How can I show the child based on their categories?
I am using JSONParser & Php code here.

Category 1
- Product A
- Product B

Category 2
- Product C
- Product D

This is the php code for show the header (category)

```
<?php
    include("koneksi.php");

    $q = mysql_query('select * from kategori_barang');

    $v = '{"info" : [';
    while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q))
    {
        $ob = array("<br>","<b>","</b>");
        if(strlen($v)<12)
        {
            $v .= '{"id_kat" : "'.$r['id_kat'].'", "kat_barang" : "'.$r['kat_barang'].'"}';
        }
        else
        {
            $v .= '{"id_kat" : "'.$r['id_kat'].'", "kat_barang" : "'.$r['kat_barang'].'"}';
        }

    }
    $v .= ']}';
    echo $v;
?>
```

Here is my database

```
`product_id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subcat_id` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_price` int(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_weight` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `product_weight_unit` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_price_unit` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `product_image` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_in_stock` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Here is my adapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

     private Context _context;
        private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
        // child data in format of header title, child title
        private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

        public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
            this._context = context;
            this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
            this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblHeader);
            lblHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            return convertView;
    }
@Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }
```

and here is my mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String link_url = "";
    String [] str=null;
    public static final String AR_ID_KAT            = "id_kat";
    public static final String AR_KAT_BARANG        = "kat_barang";

    JSONArray str_login = null;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar_buku = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    String id_kat, kat_barang;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // Listview Group click listener
        expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, long id) {
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Group Clicked " + listDataHeader.get(groupPosition),
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Listview Group expanded listener
        expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // Listview Group collasped listener
        expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        // Listview on child click listener
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                                + " : "
                                + listDataChild.get(
                                        listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                        childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Sharani Designs");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override   
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
            {
                /*arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                jsonobject = JSONParser
                        .getJSONfromURL("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/");
                        */
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/login/test_kat.php";
            JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);

                try {

                    str_login = json.getJSONArray("info");

                    for (int i = 0; i < str_login.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ar = str_login.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id  = ar.getString(AR_ID_KAT);
                        String isb = ar.getString(AR_KAT_BARANG);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();



                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(AR_ID_KAT, id);
                        map.put(AR_KAT_BARANG, isb);

                        daftar_buku.add(map);
                    }
            }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml

            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please note PhpMyadmin is a database administering tool not a database.

Comment: oh yeah I'm Sorry, what I mean is I'm using mysql as my database (using phpmyadmin)